# How to create shutdown scripts for windows 10

Tags: powershell, curl, windows-10

When my computer power downs, i would like for it to run a script that basically does an http-request to Iot devices in the network telling them that the computer has shutdown. I think i have everything needed for me to make this happen, all i need now is integrating them together.

Windows 10 has already have a feature that lets me run scripts during powerup/shutdown **gpedit.msc -> computer configuration -> windows settings -> scripts -> shutdown**

Windows 10 also has built in curl so i am planning on using that for the http request. I need to do 5 get requests before shutdown

```
curl --silent --output nul --show-error --fail 192.168.0.10/shutdown
curl --silent --output nul --show-error --fail 192.168.0.11/shutdown
curl --silent --output nul --show-error --fail 192.168.0.12/shutdown
curl --silent --output nul --show-error --fail 192.168.0.13/shutdown
curl --silent --output nul --show-error --fail 192.168.0.14/shutdown
```

in the gpedit.msc shutdown script there are 2 choices ordinary script and powershellscript, which one is better? although i have the commands the curl commands ready, i dont know how to save them. Create a file then just the commands above? what will the file extension be?

Comment: In PowerShell, `curl` is an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest`, which is not the same as the original `curl`. Just a reminder.

Comment: @stackprotector ahhh so that means if im going to use powershell ill have to remove the options, they are not important anyway they just hide the response. Which is superior the original curl or Invoke-webRequest?

Comment: If you are asking only for the file extension, you can use .bat (if not too much coding). Additional note: Task Scheduler is also another option. Based on the computer shutdown event ID, this task can be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Batch files are the easiest.
You need two batch files
One to run the curl commands
One to open the CMD window and call the first batch file

Example.  shutdown.bat is the batch that is run on shutdown
`shutdown.bat` open the `cmd` window and runs `shutdowncurl.bat`

shutdowncurl.bat

```
curl --silent --output nul --show-error --fail 192.168.0.10/shutdown
curl --silent --output nul --show-error --fail 192.168.0.11/shutdown
curl --silent --output nul --show-error --fail 192.168.0.12/shutdown
curl --silent --output nul --show-error --fail 192.168.0.13/shutdown
curl --silent --output nul --show-error --fail 192.168.0.14/shutdown
```

shutdown.bat

```
cmd /k shutdowncurl
pause
```

In this case the two batch files are in the same folder.
You could use the full path names as well

To test in Windows Explorer double click shutdown.bat or right click and choose open

After testing, remove the pause from shutdown.bat
I tested this where the shutdowncurl.bat looked like this:

```
curl --help
curl --help
curl --help
curl --help
```

Comment: Why 2 batch files? cant i just directly use the one with the curl scripts?

Comment: @DrakeJest It's just a personal preference. You could serialize all the commands into one string. cmd /k "curl --help"&& "curl --help"&& "curl --help"&& "curl --help" but that gets messy and I make more mistakes. Or use multiple CMD windows, one for each curl, with one CMD and curl per line